# Allow only one user to be an admin with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I`m creating a webpage with rails 6 , devise and cancan .

I need an admin role but i do not want to create a separate model instead i added a Boolean column to user is table , but here`s the thing ,

If any user sign up then it would be a security concern that any user would grant admin privileges only by changing the value of this column to true .

So i thought perhaps i would remove "admin" from "user_params" but then i would have to make this change from the console which is not good enough.

How i should only grant admin to specific user , my thoughts where i would only allow it for the first user only, or specific email but it feels stupid , there must be a smarter way.

How i get the application to have only one admin who can make any other user admin but only him who can do that and if any normal user signed up , no matter what he ca not manipulate this column in any way?

Best Regards

Comment: Why not add a third column - super admin? You can only allow this user to make other users normal admins

Comment: That would work , thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `admin` from `user_params` in signup controller. You don't want users to become admin just by preparing request.
2. Introduce third column `super_admin`, and grant this role from the console if you have to do it only once.
3. Create views and controllers only accessible to `super_admin` where she can update `admin` for all users.

Comment: Thanks for the tip , that would be smart solution.